# query to add data into "CLOB" column

Tags: java, sql, db2, clob

```
"INSERT into FOLDET (FOLDER_ID, FIELD_NAME, OP_VALUE,  "
        + "FIELD_VALUE, FOLDER_FIELD_TYPE, DISPLAY_FLAG ) values \n"
        + "( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) \n" ;
```

we use the above query to insert values into the table `FOLDET`

for column `FIELD_VALUE` the datatype is `varchar(32000)` , if the string length is greater than 32000 , we want to store the string in new column of `CLOB` type  eg:- say if the new column name is `FLD_VAL_EXT` of `CLOB` type added to the table `FOLDET`

i want a query to add the string to the new column if the value is greater than "32K"

Comment: It will be like super easier if you do this in java itself. Otherwise you would need to make a trigger.

Comment: The question has a Java tag...

Comment: How did I stumble on it then?

Comment: Since when MySQL has the CLOB data type?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Oracle JDBC tutorial covers this well: [Blob Insert Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html)

Basically setup the Clob by writing to its character stream before insert.